# Incorrect output after melting data in R

Tags: r

I have the code below that works, but the variable listed in df2 is not the expected X1, but outputs as the `df1[,grepl(...`.

How can I fix this issue for the melt of df1 to output X1? At the end of the day, df2 should exactly how it is, except df2[2] should be "X1".

```
packages = c("janitor", "reshape2", "ggplot2", "openxlsx", "dplyr", "readxl", "tcltk", 
             "stringi", "stringr", "viridis")

df1 <- structure(list(Days = c(3.62777777777778, 3.62847222222222, 3.62916666666667, 
                        3.62986111111111, 3.63055555555556, 3.63194444444444, 3.63333333333333, 
                        3.63402777777778, 3.63541666666667, 3.63611111111111, 3.63680555555556, 
                        3.6375, 3.63819444444444, 3.63958333333333, 3.64027777777778, 
                        3.64097222222222, 3.64166666666667, 3.64583333333333, 3.64652777777778, 
                        3.64722222222222, 3.64791666666667), X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                    NA, NA, 8930000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                    NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 98.1, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 2000:2020, class = "data.frame")

df2 <- na.omit(melt(cbind(df1[1], df1[, grepl("X1", names(df1), ignore.case = TRUE)]), id = c("Days")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using select instead of grepl fixed the issue for me.

select(df1, contains("X1", ignore.case = TRUE...

Answer (score 0):

If using base R is not a strong restriction, you can easily do this with `tidyr`. I am not quite sure how the target dataframe should look like, I'm assuming that you want `X1` and `X2`, in long format by day:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("Days")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>    Days name      value
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1  3.63 X1    8930000  
#> 2  3.63 X2         98.1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The df1 example I gave is a very small portion of my actual df1, so I need to keep the format of how I find df2 from df1.